# icinga NRPE vs. SNMP

Tags: snmp, icinga, nrpe, icinga2

Is there a list of the pro/s and con/s of NRPE vs. SNMP when using icinga?

I have no idea what's the best way to handle the returned data of plugins back to my icinga monitoring machine.

Usage of SSH as connection is no option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see no where that Icinga or Nagios use snmp to handle returned data of plugins. Icinga use nrpe and you don't need a ssh connection, nrpe bind a socket that listen on port 5666, so you have only to open tcp connection on that port.

Comment: Seems like I missunderstand the functionality of snmp. What's the difference between snmp<->nrpe? I've got plugins I need to run on the machines I need to monitor, these plugins will return status + data to my icinga monitoring server. What should I use for creating connection between icinga host system and the servers I need to monitor.

Comment: Icinga communicate with clients machines and collect data ( metrics, remote execution ... ) using nrpe. nrpe is a c binary that implement a semi protocol based on TCP/IP and which is used by Icinga, when a remote plugin is executed on the client machine the result of execution is returned by nrpe. 

You may install nrpe on your clients machines, it is a part from Icinga or nagios : apt-get install nagios-nrpe-server on ubuntu.

Comment: and where's the difference to snmp?

Comment: snmp is different ( Simple Network Management Protocol ), 
in icinga project it is only a plugin that it is used to collect and organize information about managed devices on IP networks : routers, switches, servers, workstations, printers, modem ... but it is not used as monitoring agent as like as nrpe.

Comment: Here is a similar question about snmp vs nrpe, http://serverfault.com/questions/195617/pros-cons-of-nrpe-and-snmp-with-nagios-3?rq=1